IP forwarding between two LANs without masquerading
I have two LANs connected with a VPN:
LAN1:192.168.0.0/24 <=> VPN:192.168.2.0/24 <=> LAN2:192.168.10.0/24

The two routers (one on each side of VPN) are running on Debian Linux and IPv4 forwarding is set to 1.
I have set static routes:

On LAN1:

On the router: 192.168.10.0/24 via 192.168.2.1
(other side of the VPN)
On clients:  192.168.10.0/24 via 192.168.0.202 (router IP)


On LAN2:

On the router: 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.2.2
On clients:  192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.10.10 (router IP)



On each side, I cleared iptables :
systemctl stop fail2ban
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X

Results:

From routers, I can ping other router local IP.
From LAN1, I can ping router 2 or any other machine on LAN2.
But from LAN2 (router 2 or client machine), I CANNOT ping LAN1 except router 1.

ROUTER_1 => ROUTER_2
$ traceroute -n 192.168.10.10
traceroute to 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.10.10  11.254 ms  22.074 ms  22.081 ms

ROUTER_1 => LAN2
$ traceroute -n 192.168.10.51
traceroute to 192.168.10.51 (192.168.10.51), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.2.1  12.293 ms  23.223 ms  23.230 ms
 2  192.168.10.51  23.220 ms  23.209 ms  23.199 ms

LAN1 => ROUTER_2
$ traceroute -n 192.168.10.10
traceroute to 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.202  1.730 ms  1.709 ms  1.775 ms
 2  192.168.10.10  13.219 ms  25.229 ms  25.277 ms

LAN1 => LAN2
$ traceroute -n 192.168.10.51
traceroute to 192.168.10.51 (192.168.10.51), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.202  2.442 ms  2.358 ms  2.385 ms
 2  192.168.2.1  14.530 ms  26.554 ms  26.596 ms
 3  192.168.10.51  27.433 ms  27.475 ms  27.519 ms

ROUTER_2 => ROUTER_1
$ traceroute -n 192.168.0.202
traceroute to 192.168.0.202 (192.168.0.202), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.202  11.357 ms  22.177 ms  22.123 ms

ROUTER_2 => LAN1
$ traceroute -n 192.168.0.91
traceroute to 192.168.0.91 (192.168.0.91), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.2.2  13.204 ms  24.203 ms  24.189 ms
 2  * * *
    ...
30  * * *

LAN2 => ROUTER_1
$ traceroute -n 192.168.0.202
traceroute to 192.168.0.202 (192.168.0.202), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.10.10  0.107 ms  0.087 ms  0.057 ms
 2  192.168.0.202  12.744 ms  24.551 ms  24.522 ms

LAN2 => LAN1
$ traceroute -n 192.168.0.91
traceroute to 192.168.0.91 (192.168.0.91), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.10.10  0.192 ms  0.149 ms  0.131 ms
 2  192.168.2.2  13.292 ms  25.037 ms  25.021 ms
 3  192.168.0.91  25.006 ms  24.990 ms  24.992 ms

What may be going wrong ? 
Why router2 CANNOT ping LAN1 ?
How can I fix it ?

from a LAN2 client what does traceroute -n LAN1-client (tracert -d LAN1-client if Windows) give you? Are you sure there isn't any accidential masquerading or other NAT going on? What about an unintended firewall?

Figured out what's going wrong :
I need to add routes to the VPN network (192.168.2.0/24) on each side otherwise they don't know the path to reply to ROUTER_2 as it's requests are outgoing from VPN's interface
